# Распарсить строку и проверить корректность введенных значений. Java

Tags: java, строки, парсер, ввод

Есть следующая задача: пользователь вводит команду с параметрами в консоль и в зависимости от команды и параметров выполняются определенные действия.
Например в консоли вводится:
insert 2 10

Мне нужно считать команду insert и передать в метод, который реализует insert параметры 2 и 10. 
я пошел по такому пути:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String str = sc.nextLine();
String[] s = str.split(" ");
int firstParam = new Integer(s[1]);
int secondParam = new Integer(s[2]);
if (s[0].equals("insert")) {
insert(firstParam, secondParam);
}
```

Но при этом нужно проверить корректность ввода команды и параметров. Т.е. вдруг введено
insert 2 10 15.
Тогда код тоже выполнится. Но это не верно. А если будет введено:
one one one
тогда вылетит NumberFormatException.
Получается мне нужно проверить что в массиве только 3 элемента, далее проверить все элементы соответствуют ли они ожидаемым данным и отловить ексепшены - я в правильном направлении копаю или есть более изящное решение?

Comment: Для движения к изящному решению следует начать с изучения основ компиляции. Всякие там грамматики, лексические, синтаксические анализаторы и пр. бредятина. Теория, лежащая в основе всей компьютерной мысли (академиев не проходил, сам не знаю как называется), и инструменты для облегчения задачи (flex, bison, antlr, пр.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Result{
    //класс для представления результата выполнения команд
}

public abstract class MyCommandCallback{
    void onComplete(Result result){
        //обработка успешного результата
    }
    void onError(Result result){
        //обработка ошибки
    }
}

public interface MyCommandInterface{
    MyCommand(String[] params);
    void execute(MyCommandCallback callback);
}

class Insert implements MyCommandInterface{
    Insert(String[] params){
        //тут разбираете свои аргументы и проверяете их на количество и корректность
    }
    void execute(MyCommandCallback callback){
        //тут производите необходимые действия и, в зависимости
        //от успешности, вызываете callback.onComplete() или callback.onError()
    }
}
```

ну и в основном коде

```
Scanner  sc  = new Scanner(System.in);
String   str = sc.nextLine();
String[] s   = str.split(" ");
if(s.length()==0) throw new Exception();
MyCommandInterface work;
switch(s[0]){
    case "insert":
        work=new Insert(s);
        break;
//.....
    default: throw new Exception();
}
work.execute(new MyCommandCallback(){/*.....*/});
```